# Writing to a text file using 'ofstream' code error

Tags: c++, fstream, ofstream

In C++, I am currently learning about writing to a file (let's say a txt file) using ofstream and I decided to make my own little code and try it myself. I have a question about my code, because it is not functioning the way I intended.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char opt;
    cout<<"Would you like to write to a new/existing file? [Y/N]\n";
    cin>>opt;

    if(opt=='Y'||opt=='y') {
        ofstream file;
        char filename[50];
        char statement[55];
        cout << "Please enter the name of the file you wish to open:\n";
        cin.getline(filename, 50);
        file.open(filename);
        cout << "Please enter the text you wish to be written on the file:\n";
        cin.getline(statement, 55);
        file << statement;
        file.close();
     }
     else {
         return 1;
     }
     return 0;
}
```

In the code, I ask the user whether they want to write to a file. If they enter Y, it will go into the 'if statement' and perform the code but if they enter N(or anything else), it will fail the run. My problem is that whenever I choose to say 'Y' and try to write to the file, it does not let me 'cin' the filename after it does 
    `cout<<"Please enter the name of the file you wish to open:\n";`.  It instantly asks to enter the text to be written in the file.  This error only occurs when I use the if statement and ask the user if they would like to write into the file.  If I remove the 'if statement' and take the code inside the 'if statement' and write it into the main itself without giving the user the option to enter Y or N, the code works fine. So I know that it is not an error in the code inside the if statement, it has something to do with my concept of understanding how this code should be working! Please excuse my stupidity of there is something obvious that I am missing, but I can't seem to find the reason.

**SOLUTION:** For anyone who had the same problem, all you have to do is `cin.ignore();` after `cin.getline();`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=getline+skipping

Answer (score 0):

You can use write method of ofstream [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/write/) is example